# How to load MoCo model weights that are stored as an state_dict?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am new to PyTorch and I am trying to load the MoCo model in order to use it.

In the following [repo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/moco) I have found the code and also, I downloaded the pre-trained model (`moco_v2_800ep_pretrain.pth.tar`) which is a state_dict with the model’s weights.

I know that in order to use a model I need to create a model instance first and then load the state_dict.

My problem is that I can not create an instance model of MoCo. I saw the code on GiHub and I end up with the following code:

```py
    moco = torch.load('moco_v2_800ep_pretrain.pth.tar')
    moco_state_dict = moco['state_dict']

    my_moco_model = MoCo(base_encoder, dim=128, K=65536, m=0.999, T=0.07, mlp=False)
    my_moco_model.load_state_dict(new_dict)
```

I do not know what to put in the base_encoder parameter or tell me if there is another way to load the model.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/github/facebookresearch/moco/blob/colab-notebook/colab/moco_cifar10_demo.ipynb Please check this example colab, there they show how to train & test the model.